# On the profile page, the order of posts with "votes" sorting is different in "all" and "{post-type}" tabs when you have only {post-type} posts

Tags: discussion, profile-page, sorting

Let's assume there's a user who has only questions and no answers. Indeed, there're many of these. I'll pick one and go to their profile page.

I sort the posts by votes. Then I compare the order of the "all" posts and only "questions". They are different for no good reason - the posts with the same score get rearranged, making the illusion that something changes, but in fact nothing changes. It doesn't make the list incorrect, but it's just unclear, why should the order be different.

Here's the illustration. See, all the posts the user has are questions.

> [image]